# Why using variables in hive adds 18k mappers?

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive, hiveql

Query A:

```
create table tmp_test as
select external_id from my_events where day>'2017-03-05' limit 20;
```

Query B:

```
set FIRST_DAY='2017-03-05';
create table tmp_test as
select external_id from my_events where day>'${FIRST_DAY}' limit 20;
```

Why does B use 18k mappers while A uses only 160? Is it normal or am I the only one getting it?

PS. my_events is partitioned by day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your 2ns query the variable is not being expended and the query is **literarily** executed with the predicate -

```
day > '${FIRST_DAY}'
```

which probably cause all the partitions to be included

---

The right syntax would be -

```
set FIRST_DAY='2017-03-05';
... day > date ${hiveconf:FIRST_DAY} ...
```

(The date is qualified)

or

```
set FIRST_DAY=2017-03-05;
... day > date '${hiveconf:FIRST_DAY}' ...
```

(The placeholder is qualified)

P.s. if `day` is of string type then remove the preceding `date`

[VariableSubstitution](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+VariableSubstitution)

---

Please note that the following syntax (double use of qualifiers) will yield a syntax error -

```
set FIRST_DAY='2017-03-05';
... day > date '${hiveconf:FIRST_DAY}' ...
```

since after the variable expansion the query will look like this -

```
... day > date ''2017-03-05'' ...
```

Comment: Thanks, that solved the issue. Strangely enough when I experimented with just select, it didn't seem to be slowed down.

Comment: You're welcome. Simple SELECT does not use map-reduce. If you'll select the partition column too, you'll probably see that you are retrieving rows from partitions before 2017-03-05